# rotate angles by 90 degrees pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trigonometry

I'm returning the angle at each point in time from a single point using `np.arctan`. The direction is crudely pictured in the compass below.

This is fine but I'm hoping to rotate the *compass* by 90 degrees anti-clockwise. I've included a second crude compass below to show the intended orientation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({  
    'Time' : ['2021-03-27 10:46:48.100','2021-03-27 10:46:48.200','2021-03-27 10:46:48.300','2021-03-27 10:46:48.400'],        
    'id' : ['A','A','A','A'],                             
    'x' : [50.0,55.0,50.0,50.0],
    'y' : [25.0,20.0,20.0,15.0],             
    })


x = df.groupby('id')['x'].diff().fillna(0).astype(float) 
y = df.groupby('id')['y'].diff().fillna(0).astype(float) 

df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(x, y) 
df['Alpha'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])
```

out:

```
                      Time id     x     y  Rotation  Alpha
0  2021-03-27 10:46:48.100  A  50.0  25.0  0.000000    0.0
1  2021-03-27 10:46:48.200  A  55.0  20.0 -0.785398  135.0
2  2021-03-27 10:46:48.300  A  50.0  20.0  3.141593  -90.0
3  2021-03-27 10:46:48.400  A  50.0  15.0 -1.570796  180.0
```

intended output:

```
                      Time id     x     y  Rotation    Alpha
0  2021-03-27 10:46:48.100  A  50.0  25.0  0.000000      0.0
1  2021-03-27 10:46:48.200  A  55.0  20.0  2.356194   -135.0
2  2021-03-27 10:46:48.300  A  50.0  20.0 -1.570796      0.0
3  2021-03-27 10:46:48.400  A  50.0  15.0  3.141593    -90.0
```

original orientation

```
               0
          -45  |  45
               | 
       -90 <---x---> 90
               | 
         -135  |  135
              180
```

Intended orientation

```
               90
          45   |    135
               | 
         0 <---x---> 180
               | 
         -45   |  -135
              -90
```

Comment: is not it `np.arctan2(y, x)` since it is `y/x`?

Comment: No. `TypeError: ufunc() missing 1 of 2required positional argument(s)`

Comment: no I am saying it should be `df['Rotation'] = np.arctan2(y, x)` since it is y/x

Comment: Sorry. No, it just flips the orientation. I need the angle rotated as well.

Comment: Can you not just add 90 to the angles?

Comment: Yeh but it's not full 360 degrees. It's 0-180, -1,-179

Comment: don't fully understand, it is already like that for example `EAST` `np.arctan2(0, np.Infinity)` is `0 °` `WEST` `np.arctan2(0, -np.Infinity)` `180 °`, `NORTH` `np.arctan2(np.Infinity, 0)` `90 °`, `SOUNTH` `np.arctan2(-np.Infinity, 0)` `-90 °`

Comment: I've included a rough compass.

Comment: original orientation is not what you have shown, wast is 0' and west is 180' and again you are mixing x,y and y,x

Comment: Yeh, I prefer `x/y` as the `North` is `90`, `West` is `0` and `South` is `-90`. If y/x, then `North` is `0`, `West` is `90` and `South` is `180`. Suppose it doesn't really matter though. I just need to rotate _any_ angle by 90 degrees anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Rotate by 90 degrees
angles = np.arctan2(x, y) + np.pi / 2

# Bring back into range -179..180
angles[angles > np.pi] -= 2 * np.pi
```

The angle of the first row is changed as well, but as both x and y are 0 there, the angle is not properly defined anyway, you'll need to decide what to do in this case. It could be zero'd out like this:

```
angles[(x==0) & (y==0)] = 0
```

Then set the Pandas columns as before:

```
df['Rotation'] = angles
df['Alpha'] = np.degrees(df['Rotation'])

                      Time id     x     y  Rotation  Alpha
0  2021-03-27 10:46:48.100  A  50.0  25.0  0.000000    0.0
1  2021-03-27 10:46:48.200  A  55.0  20.0 -2.356194 -135.0
2  2021-03-27 10:46:48.300  A  50.0  20.0  0.000000    0.0
3  2021-03-27 10:46:48.400  A  50.0  15.0 -1.570796  -90.0
```